# Sliding window approach using SVR & LightGBM

Tags: neural-network, time-series, svm, forecast, lightgbm

I'm working on a multivariate time series forecast using a couple of ML algorithms (Neural Networks, Support Vector Machines & Gradient boosting algorithms). I need to measure the performance of each model. 
I've implemented the 1st model using Tensorflow 2.0. Training & testing data was created using `tf.Dataset` API. 
The data format is `(window_data, forecast)`, where `window_data` represents a set of 24 timesteps and `forecast` represents  the next timestep.

Now I need to train 2nd & 3rd model using SVR (LinearSVR to be more precise) and LightGBM. 
Is it possible to feed the model with a windowed dataset like in my 1st model?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is designed to really make your life easier (especially with the fancy new additions with the 2.0 version). I think you should use pandas to generate sliding windows: I would think that for a N sized time series with K lookback window you will have N-K+1 examples by sliding lookback.

And while you're at it have you treated your lookback window as a hyperparameter? i.e optimise your model performance on a validation test by searching the best lookback?

Comment: The implementation of a sliding window isn't the problem. I'm asking if it's possible to feed the dataset as a windowed dataset. For my TF model I've used CNN & LSTM which both accept a 3 dimensional dataset [samples, timestemps, features]. Whereas SVM & lightGBM accept only 2D data as input. I haven't tried to tune the window sizes parameter. Will try it.